# C Compiler Pointless Errors?

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, strcpy

I have the following code written in C:

```
n.    struct UDSData {
        char *name;
        char *address;
      };

n.    char UDS1[16] = "fill up sixteen", UDS2[16] = "fill up sixteen";

n.    while (something) {
       ...

108.   char UDS1Temp[16], UDS2Temp[16];
109.   strcpy(UDS1Temp, UDS1);
110.   strcpy(UDS2Temp, UDS2);
111.   
112.   struct UDSData item = {UDS1Temp, UDS2Temp};
113.   UDSCodes[UDSTotal++] = item;
     }
```

Any idea why the code compiles to give these errors:

```
1><file>(112): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1><file>(113): error C2065: 'item' : undeclared identifier
1><file(113): error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'UDSData'
```

Removing the `strcpy()` and inputting `UDS1` and `UDS2` directly into the struct works.

Comment: Line 112 doesn't make a lot of sense to me but I'm not up to date on C. Which C standard are you using and what type is UDSData?

Comment: Sounds like the compiler does not find this type `UDSData`. Is it defined properly? (`include`d header, no circular dependencies, etc.)?

Comment: @KirilKirov Yes, this type is previously defined. As I had mentioned, it works just fine if I replace UDS1Temp with UDS1, and UDS2Temp with UDS2 in the struct.

Comment: Is the code too long? It will be easier for us to help you if we have the whole code and we can actually try to compile something by ourselves.

Comment: @KirilKirov It's pretty huge and it requires very specialized input in order for it to function... otherwise I would post more.

Comment: Before C99 all variables needed to be declared at the start of a function.  `UDS1Temp` and `item` appear to violate this.  Which version of C are you trying to compile using?

Comment: @simonc I tried bringing the declarations to the start, but there was not luck.

Comment: "no luck" as in precisely the same compiler errors?  If not, what were the updated errors?

Comment: That isn't what you say in your question: "Removing the strcpy() ... works."

Answer (score 2):

You are almost certainly using an early compiler standard, like C89, which does not allow mixed declarations and code.  You need to declare `item` near the start of the code block.  Something like this:

```
char UDS1Temp[16], UDS2Temp[16];
struct UDSData item = {UDS1Temp, UDS2Temp};

strcpy(UDS1Temp, UDS1);
strcpy(UDS2Temp, UDS2);
UDSCodes[UDSTotal++] = item
```

Since you are only placing the pointers into the struct, the initialisation can be done before the `strcpy`.  But you must declare `UDSData` *after* the two char arrays.